# how to arrange the plots in pdf via ODS options

Tags: pdf, sas

Say I have a macro named `%mplot` which generates 2 plots each time I call.

I want to place 2 plots in the first page, then 6 plots in second pages, then 4 plots in the last page. (I have tested one page can have at most 6 plots).

I guess the code should be something like this

```
ods ... ;
%mplot(t1);
%mplot(t2);
ods ...;
%mplot(t3);
%mplot(t4);
%mplot(t5);
%mplot(t6);
%mplot(t7);
%mplot(t8);;
ods ...;
%mplot(t9);
%mplot(t10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the ODS PDF STARTPAGE option:

```
ods pdf startpage=no;
```